# Proving a matrix inequality in quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Consider $D_{1},D_{2},D_{3}$ real positive $N\times N$ diagonal matrices, with $D_{1}\iota\leq\iota$ ($\iota$ is the vector of ones). Let matrix $A$ be a real positive $N\times N$ matrix with $A\iota<\iota$. Let $M\equiv I-D_{1}A^{T}$ and let $\mathcal{D}(v)$ denote the diagonal matrix formed by the elements of vector $v$. I want to show the following inequality, which seems true in numerical simulations:
$$M^{-1}\left(I-D_{1}\right)D_{1}\mathcal{D}\left\{ A^{T}M^{-1}D_{2}\iota\right\} D_{3}M^{-T}\left(I-A\right)D_{3}^{-1}\iota\leq M^{-1}D_{2}\iota.$$

Note that if $A$ is a diagonal matrix then this simplifies to $$\left(I-D_{1}\right)D_{1}A \left(I-A\right) M^{-1}M^{-1}\leq I,$$ which is true by virtue of the fact that if $x,y \in [0,1]$ then $x(1-x)y(1-y)(1-xy)^2 \leq 1$.